# Matching any three columns value out of five columns

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I am actually picking record from Oracle db based on three column fields at a time. User may provide any three columns from the defined five columns. I have tried below two queries and Query-1 is much faster that the second one here despite of Query-1 is having an extra joining. What is the reason behind that?

Query-1

```
select y.id,y.form_no, y.ownership, y.issue_date, y.issue_place, y.pin_no,surname, y.given_names, y.date_of_birth_bs
    from (
        select form_no,
        case when lower(place_of_birth) = 'morang' then 1 else 0 end as PlaceOfBirth,
        case when date_of_birth_ad = to_date('1985-09-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') then 1 else 0 end as DateOfBirthAd,
        case when issue_date = '20600219' then 1 else 0 end as DateOfIssue,
        case when lower(issue_place) = 'morang' then 1 else 0 end as PlaceOfIssue,
        case when lower(ownership) = '12005-1746' then 1 else 0 end as ownershipNo
        from application
    ) x, application y
where x.form_no = y.form_no and (x.PlaceOfBirth + x.DateOfBirthAd + x.DateOfIssue + x.PlaceOfIssue + x.ownershipNo) > 2;
```

Query-2

```
select id,form_no, ownership, issue_date, issue_place, pin_no,surname, given_names, date_of_birth_bs
from application y
where
    (case when lower(place_of_birth) = 'morang' then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when date_of_birth_ad = to_date('1985-09-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when issue_date = '20600219' then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when lower(issue_place) = 'morang' then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when lower(ownership) = '12005-1746' then 1 else 0 end) > 2;
```

Also, is there any other way to modify the query to make it faster?

Comment: Do you have indexes on `lower( place_of_birth )`, `lower( issue_place )` and `lower( ownership )`?

Comment: @MT0 Yes, I have index. But I think it doesn't matter as I am running the two different queries on same database.

Comment: Post explain plans for both queries. It's possible the first query allows use of the index(es) whereas the 2nd query causes the CBO to prefer a full table scan. Also, note that there is a slight logical difference between these two queries - the first will only return rows where form_no is not null, unlike the 2nd query.

Comment: Also, please verify that you are testing the performance by running both queries *to completion* (i.e. you don't just stop after the first page of results).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the second query you may define a function based index

```
create index fidx on application ((case when lower(place_of_birth) = 'morang' then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when date_of_birth_ad = to_date('1985-09-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when issue_date = '20600219' then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when lower(issue_place) = 'morang' then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when lower(ownership) = '12005-1746' then 1 else 0 end));
```

to get a INDEX RANGE SCAN access.

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                   | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT            |             | 40307 |  5117K|   112   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|   1 |  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| APPLICATION | 40307 |  5117K|   112   (0)| 00:00:02 |
|*  2 |   INDEX RANGE SCAN          | FIDX        |  7255 |       |    19   (0)| 00:00:01 |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

   2 - access(CASE LOWER("PLACE_OF_BIRTH") WHEN 'morang' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +CASE 
              "DATE_OF_BIRTH_AD" WHEN TO_DATE(' 1985-09-01 00:00:00', 'syyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') 
              THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +CASE "ISSUE_DATE" WHEN '20600219' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +CASE 
              LOWER("ISSUE_PLACE") WHEN 'morang' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +CASE LOWER("OWNERSHIP") WHEN 
              '12005-1746' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END >2)
```

The problem with this approach is that it works only for the exact literal values as in your query.
If you can use other parameters (e.g. using bind variables) this will not work.

As an alternative you may *rewrite the query* adding some *OR connected* access predicates and add dedicated indices for them.

**Example**

```
create index fidx1 on application ( lower(place_of_birth) );
create index fidx2 on application ( issue_date );
create index fidx3 on application ( lower(ownership) );
```

The enhanced query would be

```
select id,form_no, ownership, issue_date, issue_place, pin_no,surname, given_names, date_of_birth_bs
from application y
where /*ACCESS */
    (lower(place_of_birth) = 'morang' or
     issue_date = '20600219' or
     lower(ownership) = '12005-1746' ) and
    /* FILTER */
    ((case when lower(place_of_birth) = 'morang' then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when date_of_birth_ad = to_date('1985-09-01', 'yyyy-MM-dd') then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when issue_date = '20600219' then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when lower(issue_place) = 'morang' then 1 else 0 end)+
    (case when lower(ownership) = '12005-1746' then 1 else 0 end) > 2);
```

Note the added three access predicates

```
(lower(place_of_birth) = 'morang' or
 issue_date = '20600219' or
 lower(ownership) = '12005-1746' )
```

which enable a INDEX CONCATENATION ACCESS

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name        | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |             |   824 |   125K|  1597   (1)| 00:00:20 |
|   1 |  CONCATENATION               |             |       |       |            |          |
|*  2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| APPLICATION |   411 | 64116 |   798   (1)| 00:00:10 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | FIDX3       |  3404 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| APPLICATION |   407 | 63492 |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | FIDX1       |  3404 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  6 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| APPLICATION |     6 |   936 |   798   (1)| 00:00:10 |
|*  7 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | FIDX2       |  3404 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Why three OR connected predicates?

If you have three columns out of five to match, you may skip two of them and match the remaining three colums with OR - one of the them **must** match.

So one approch to tune your query is to get the three most selective column / expresions and define the index / function based index on them and add  the access predicates as shown above.

Test in advance - you will have to do three index range scans and concatenate the results - so if the cost of index access is high (the index access returns too much records) you will fall back in FULL TABLE SCAN
(which is probably your currect access path).

Comment: You are right about the `/*ACCESS */` portion in `where` clause.